# EOF detection by ZLib Gzip API?

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

I have a sample example of `Gzip Compressed Data | 100-length RNG Pad`. Surprisingly the `zlib` [GZip file API](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip) is able to detect EOF at the start of the n-length pad and not count it in. [Try Online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaa97b7d800f29a2)

I tried looking at the [header](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gzip.html) and [source code](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/gzread.c) and these were my best guesses:

1. **Based on Source code** - Detects a stream corruption due to encountering an invalid byte sequence - consequently `gzread` returns -1.
2. **Based on File Header** - Detects the CRC32 at the end during the last `read` and checks the corresponding file size after it. If things match up it returns EOF.

Could someone confirm my understanding that (1) is indeed happening. If this is the case Im guessing that the example case I tried out could be undefined behavior based on the random byte sequence.

Comment: Is there some problem with the question - I can rephrase or edit accordingly if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about zlib detecting that it's getting random data that supposed to be a gzip stream, then yes, it will usually do that within a small number of bytes based on violations of the header format or the deflate format.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So there seems to be a minuscule chance that a random stream of bytes concatenated at the end of a gzip file might not violate the deflate format, in turn not hitting EOF and thus the above code would fail?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "fail", since I don't know what your requirements are. There is a vanishingly small chance that random data replacing the contents of part of a gzip stream will still look like a valid gzip stream if the deflate data is valid _and_ the CRC and length at the end match _and_ that all happened to end exactly where your data ended originally.